# Is this code safe from SQL injection and other types of attack? (If it is why?)

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering Is this code safe form SQL injection and other types of exploits? If it is safe can anyone explain it to me how? And if isn't can anyone make corrections

```
<?php     
$servername = "localhost";       
$username = "root";    
 $password = "";    
 $dbname = "form";    

//Requesting values form form.html    
$a = $_REQUEST['fname'];    
$b = $_REQUEST['lname'];    
$c = $_REQUEST['email'];    

// Create connection    
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);     
// Check connection     
if ($conn->connect_error) {    
    die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);    
 } 

// prepare and bind     
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO my_db (fname, lname, email)    
  VALUES (?, ?, ?)");    
 $stmt->bind_param("sss",$a,$b,$c);    

$stmt->execute();    

echo "new record created successfully";    

$stmt->close();    
 $conn->close();     
?>
```

Comment: Yes, it can be said that it's safe from at least mysql injection. Reason: The query is executed in such a way that the user input isn't directly entered into the mysql query. But I suggest you to google down for more info.

Comment: Is it unsafe from other kinds of attacks?

Comment: No answer from you. @Adi219

Comment: @revo I deleted my answer as it received two downvotes and someone who appears to be an expert at SQL told me that my approach wouldn't work (as the parameters are binded)

Comment: Yes, it is unsafe from XSS type attack.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Sanu_012 — Nonsense. The only thing it outputs is a hardcoded string. It is immune to XSS.

Comment: @Sanu_012 you cannot judge XSS from this code. XSS can be protected by output sanitizing.

Comment: @Adi219 I always give reason when down-voting, but unfortunately not everyone do that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe from SQL Injection, but it can be still improved security wise.

SQL Injection is when you concatenate sql query with user parameters, this gives malicious user a chance to inject data or perform dangerous actions in your database.

Assuming you have a code:

```
$query = 'select * from user where id = ' + $_GET['id'];
```

Now assume a hacker send the id param as 1 or 1 = 1, so your query becomes

```
select * from user where id = 1 or 1 = 1
```

This will return all users.There are also other ways to inject

Since you are using prepared statement and bind all parameters, it's not possible to concatenate sql query.

**Security wise**,

- your code accept $_REQUEST, this includes both GET and POST. This is not a good practice. You should restrict CRUD to POST only.
- You are using root (even in develop environment, you shouldn't use root)

Comment: down-voter, please explain.